# Unable to download a file by setting Firefox profile using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to handle file download using selenium.For this, I used the following code to set the firefox profile:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
            "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
   "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
```

Through my UI, I am downloading 2 files.
First file, I am successfully able to download whose pop up comes like this :

[image]

But I am unable to download the second file. For the second file, the popup is like the one below:
[image]

I am not sure why my firefox profile settings are not able to handle the download for the second file.

Kindly suggest. Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: it seems first file is of format Microsoft office excel 97-2003 worksheet and second one is Microsoft Office ExcelWorksheet(newer version) , so it cannot find the opening application.Try to save it by clicking on save and then try to open.

Comment: @Naruto I belive it's really not easy to do (maybe even not possible) (click to save) - using only selenium.

Comment: is it a requirement to use selenium? or i can suggest another way?

Comment: @Sammi can you please give us a clarity on, if by clicking one download button will pop up with two download instances or you need to click the button one after the other to get these two pupups..... the code looks as if two popups appear by clicking one download link....

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenide](http://selenide.org/), you could try something like this and then compare it to what you are doing:

```
@Test
    public void userCanDownloadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
     // Folder to store downloads and screenshots to.
     reportsFolder = "./src/test/profiles/chrome/downloads/";

     open("http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.16/");

     // Download files
     $("a[href='/2.16/chromedriver_win32.zip']").download();
        $(By.xpath(".//a[@href='/2.16/chromedriver_mac32.zip']")).download();

        // Count files in folder, assert 2
        int downloadsCount = new File(reportsFolder+"2.16").listFiles().length;
        assertEquals("Should be 2 files but founded " + downloadsCount,  
              downloadsCount, 2); 

        // Clean after test
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(reportsFolder+"2.16"));
    }
```